# python bypassing raw_input by passing in other raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm creating a text based adventure game. The character is navigating a map made up of city blocks. I have a `direction_function` that takes `raw_input` and then moves the character to the correct adjacent block. However, I have special features, like items to pick up or people to interact with on most blocks. Here I use `raw_input` as well. If they enter the right keyword they interact, but if they ignore them by entering a direction, it passes them into the `direction_function` which prompts them for `raw_input` again. Is there a way to pass their initial answer into the `direction_function` so they don't have to repeat their answer?

here's my direction_function:

```
def direction_function(left, right, up, down, re):
    direc = raw_input(">")
    if direc in west:
        left()
    elif direc in east:
        right()
    elif direc in north:
        up()
    elif direc in south:
        down()
    elif direc in inventory_list:
        inventory_check()
        re()
    else:
        print "try again"
        re()
```

I designate a function for each block like this

```
def block3_0():
    print "You see a bike lying in your neighbor's yard. Not much else of interest."
    direc = raw_input(">")
    if direc in ("take bike", "steal bike", "ride bike", "borrow bike", "use bike"):
        print "\n"
        bike.remove("bike")
        school_route()
    else:
        direction_function(block2_0, block4_0, block3_1, block3_0, block3_0)
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Only the relevant parts, not necessarily all the dialogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a default argument value on your `direction_function` to pass the result of an eventual previous call to `raw_input`, such as:

```
def direction_function(direction=None):
    direction = direction or raw_input()
    # Do something with the input
```

If no direction is provided (regular workflow), the test will end up calling `raw_input` to get some. If a direction is provided (like the one you'll pass if you already read one), it will directly be used.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you just have to define your function in such a way to make this possible.

For instance, consider something like this:

```
def direction_function(input = 'default_val'):
    if input != 'default_val':
        input = raw_input()

    # do your stuff here
```

With your function structured like the above, what you can do is check for interaction values or direction condition in the code block where you call your direction_function() method and pass it the input value taken where the function was called. So if direction is what the player opts for, then the input should be 'default_val'.

Comment: With this code, if the input (don't use the name `input`, it overshadows a builtin) is anything but the default value, it will get overwritten by a `raw_input` call, preventing passing a value in.